# arrange weekdays according to country

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, sapui5

I want to display sequence of weekdays according to country. How can I achieve this using `SAPUI5` and `Javascript` or `jQuery`

Sequence according to country should be

```
India: Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun

Dubai: Sun, Mon, ...
```

Comment: I can't speach for "sapui5", but there's nothing built into JavaScript or jQuery that gives you this information.

Comment: Please provide more information or create jsfiddle...

Comment: you have to make your own list, there are not so many countries or variations of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAPUI5 actually does contain information for this.
Have a look at the [getFirstDayOfWeek](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.LocaleData.html#getFirstDayOfWeek) method of the LocaleData object.

To get the first day of the week for Dubai and India:

```
new sap.ui.core.LocaleData(new sap.ui.core.Locale("ar_AE")).getFirstDayOfWeek()
// => 6

new sap.ui.core.LocaleData(new sap.ui.core.Locale("en_IN")).getFirstDayOfWeek()
// => 0
```

Or you could get the current locale from the browser / OS settings:

```
new sap.ui.core.LocaleData(sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getLocale()).getFirstDayOfWeek()
```